# Identify class attribute type and call its function

Tags: python, class, oop

I have defined a class `Field`. I have also defined `A` and `B`, which are child classes of `Field`.

Now I have defined another class `Tool`. It can contain class variable which can either be of type class `Field`, or other class, or a *normal* variable. If variable is of type `Field` then call `fun1` and collect results.

Please suggest any way that I can do. I am very new to object oriented programming.

```
class Field(object):
  def fun1(self):
    return 'Field'

class A(Field):
  def fun1(self):
    return 'A fun1'

class B(Field):
  def fun1(self):
    return 'B fun1'

class Tool(object):
  a1 = A()
  b1 = B()
  c1 = 'abc'

  def fun1(self):
    all_attributes = dir(self)
    result_list = []
    for attribute in all_attributes:
      if attribute is of type Field:
        result_list.append(attribute.fun1())
  return return_list
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `isinstance` builtin:

```
if isinstance(attribute, Field):
    ...
```

or possibly:

```
if isinstance(getattr(self, attribute), Field):
    ...
```

since it looks like `attribute` may be the string name of the attribute in your code.

It should be noted that generally, it's better to construct your data so that it includes all homogonous types.  Then you don't need to do any type-checking, etc -- though it's hard to say whether that advice can be helpful with the generic example code you've posted in the question.

Comment: But when i get list of attributes using dir() they are all of string type how can i know its type

Comment: @Rohit.nib -- Right, that why I say it's hard to give advice here.  Introspecting the attributes on `self` is a bit of an odd thing to do.  _usually_ you want to _know_ what the attributes are (and their types) ahead of time .

Comment: I have just written a sudo code just to explain what i need. can we do it some other way. I just wanted to execute functions of obj depending on its type

Comment: @Rohit.nib -- You _can_ do it this way.  However, I suspect you'll find that as you continue on this path, the code will get more muddled and difficult to work with.  IMHO, the code will be cleanest if you don't need to introspect the types to call the functions (i.e. if all the types that will be in the collections provide the same interface).  In this case, I might add a `fields` attribute to your `Tool` which is just a list (or dict) of fields to work with.  Wherever you are adding `Field` instances to `Tool` currently, just add them to `tool.fields` instead.

Comment: @Rohit.nib if you do want to continue with introspection you would just do `member = getattr(self, attribute)` then do the instance checking on `member`.